# proving a unit ball from given conditions

Tags: vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This came up in a derivation I was going through. I can clearly see this in 2D but how do i show in $n$ dimension.

Given $x^Ty\le 1$ for all $\|y\|_2=1$ for $x,y\in R^n$, show that $\|x\|_2 \le 1$?

Cauchy-Schwartz did not lead me to any insights.

In fact I seem to be butting my head to the wrong conclusion via this route, which intuitively seems leading to a wrong result.
$$x^Tx \ge (x^Ty)^2$$ by CS and using $y^Ty=1$. Now, using $(x+y)^T(x+y)\geq 0$ we can show
$$(x^Ty)^2\geq \left(-\frac{1}{2} (1+x^Tx)\right)^2$$
These two lead to $x^Tx = 1$. I am stumped.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but it seems that if $y = [0\;1]^\textsf{T}$ and $x = [2\;0]^\textsf{T}$, you have $x^\textsf{T}y = 0 \leq 1$ and $\|y\|_2 = 1$, but $\|x\|_2 = 2 > 1$.

Comment: sorry @BrianTung good point, I forgot to mention it correctly (am editing the qeeustion) we have to prove for all y such that $\|y\|_2=1$

Comment: OK, then I would consider the vector parallel to $x$ with unit norm—i.e., $x/\|x\|$. Suppose you set $y$ to that vector, then what?

Comment: Not sure what that leads two, but in 2D $\|y\|_2=1$ is the unit circle centered at origin. Now for any general vector x in this plane, the only way its inner product with any point on this circle is less than 1, is if it lies within the circle, showing that $\|x\|\le 1$. I can't seem to show this in $n$ dimension.

Comment: What is the norm of $x^\textsf{T}x/\|x\|$?

Comment: I think for all $y$ would mean that you can choose x, only for all $y$ such that $\|y\|_2=1$. By fixing $x$ and then making $y$ depend on it, aren't you going the other way round? Do you see your $x^Tx /  \|x\|$ argument working in 2D as well, against my comment above? I think this results (what I asked for) makes sense in 2D.

Comment: Take your example, for an x your chose $y=x/\|x\|$ and for this you show the $x^Ty \le 1$. Well enough, But this x is acceptable in the solution set only if for all allowable y, you can show $x^Ty\le 1$,  i.e. for y = [1, 0, 0 ,.....] is $x_1 \le 1$? etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138620/discussion-between-manav-and-brian-tung).

Answer (score 1):

@Brian's hint helped me understand my misunderstanding.

For a given x, one can construct a y of unit norm ($x/\|x\|$) and then can show the result.